# HTML <table> with legend inside of it

Tags: html

I currently have a table structure for what I need.
I have something like the following

```
Field1   Field3  Field5
Field2   Field4  Field6
```

Note that Field1,Field2 are in a `<td>`, Field3,Field4 are in a `<td>`, Field5, Field6 are in a `<td>`.

I like to put a `<legend>` around say Field1,Field2 but I have a issue as legends cannot go inside of a `<tr>`. How can I then add a legend. One alternative that I thought about was to just scrap the `<table>` like I am doing now and use `<div>`. Please let me know if this would be the correct way of going about this or if there is a way to add `<legend>` the way I need it.

Comment: By "a" do you mean the anchor tag?

Comment: sorry, no "a" is not for anchor tag. "a" just means a

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you describe your desired output and probably for what purpose?

Comment: legend belongs in a fieldset..

Comment: Yes, I understand. Sorry I did not state that. I cannot though have fieldset inside of <tr>

Comment: What is your end goal? Perhaps it can achieved in a different way other than legends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, you want a legend for two fields that are inside a table cell. This is simple:

```
<td>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your legend here</legend>
        Field1
        Field2
    </fieldset>
</td>
```

Whether this addresses the question you wanted to ask is a different matter. The question is very abstract and does not give a hint of what you are really doing, or what the real problem is.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you really want is a `caption`, not a `legend`.

It fulfils much the same role as a caption, but is meant for use in `table` elements.

If it is the case that you are just using a table for layout, rather than for tabulated data then you should re-consider.